# CPP Program Does Not Run

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm new to C++ and I have written an example in CodeBlocks to see how this program works. Here is the program:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

class GradeBook
{
    public:
        GradeBook( string name )
        {
            setCourseName( name );
        }
        void setCourseName( string name )
        {
            courseName = name;
        }
        string getCourseName()
        {
            return courseName;
        }
        void displayMessage()
        {
            cout << "Welcome to the gradebook for \n" << getCourseName() << "!" << endl;
        }
    private:
        string courseName;
};

int main()
{
    GradeBook gradeBook1("Introduction to C++");
    cout << gradeBook1.displayMessage() << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

And as you can see I have called a `displayMessage` function at *main* and it basically should print out a statement based on the argument that I have called ealier in `gradeBook1` object.

But the problem is, it does not start and I don't know why!

And here is the error log:

```
  ||=== Build: Debug in Youtube (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\C++_Tutorials\Youtube\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\C++_Tutorials\Youtube\main.cpp|35|error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'void')|
```

Comment: Here's your problem: cout << gradeBook1.displayMessage() << endl; and you are calling void displayMessage(). Just invoke gradeBook1.displayMessage(); then it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gradeBook1.displayMessage()` is a void function. Nothing to print in this line ->

```
cout << gradeBook1.displayMessage() << endl;
```

remove `cout`. Just type ->

```
gradeBook1.displayMessage();
```

Hope it helps. :)